# What is the syntax of jquery for button submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is as follows:
with button click, want to hide those paragraphs

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Click me to hide paragraphs</button>
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Click me to hide paragraphs</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Really appreciated.